# Set value of element using an input variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js function that sets the value of `id_2` based on the value of `id_1`. It looks like this below:

```
function set_value(id_1, id_2, url){
    var id_1_value;
    id_1_value = $(id_1).val();
    var value;
    ...
    /* calculation etc. */
    document.getElementById(id_2).value = value;
};
```

The function is linked to the `id_1` html element by an onchange method like this `onchange='set_value(this, id_2)'`.

If I change the value in `id_1` the function doesn't work and I get the following error in the console:

```
Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference
```

but if I hardcode `document.getElementById('id_2')` in the function it works fine. How do I write this function so I can pass an element id variable to it successfully? I want to reuse this function for different elements you see...

Comment: Sorry that was an error, just changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `set_value` function should be as below.

```
function set_value(id_1, id_2, url) {
    var id_1_value = $(id_1).val();
    /* calculation etc. */
    if ($(id_2).length !== 0)
    {
        $(id_2).val(id_1_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm going for this one because I want to avoid having to add quotes to my input variable. The ```onchange=set_value(this, id_2)``` part is autogenerated using my django code

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing "#id_2" to the set_value parameter?

if so that means it would return null.

```
// The function should be called like this 
 var id_2 =  "id_2";
 set_value(this, id_2, blah...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the call like this

```
onchange='set_value(this, "id_2")'
```

Second parameter should be passed as string.

Answer (score 0):

try this following code:

```
function set_value(id_1, id_2, url){
    var id_1_value = $(id_1).val();
    var value;
    ...
    /* calculation etc. */
    document.getElementById(id_2).value = value;
};
```

and onchange function

```
onchange="set_value(this, 'id_2')"
```